# Getting high RPM out of a low RPM motor

Tags: gears, energy

I'm trying to use a 1500 RPM-rated electric motor to accelerate a (light, 25kg) shaft up to 50 000 RPM. At these speeds I figure using a belt system or roller chains is out of the question due to wear and friction; are these kinds of speeds possible to achieve reliably with a mechanical transmission or do I need to turn to hydraulic transmission? Or what is an efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need something like a [turboprop transmission](http://www.cutawaycreations.com/cutaways.php?project=pratt-whitney-pt6-turboprop-engine#/IMAGES/pratt-whitney-pt6-turboprop-engine/images/image4.jpg) operating in reverse. These are generally planetary gearboxes for good balance at high speeds.

[image]